# mogoose aggregate lookup on the field of object unwind not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to lookup from question document while showing some results of users. there is a field with name questionAnswer of type array in user schema. also i am unwinging the array field but only returing the questions but answer field. whats i am doing wrong please guide me.

here is my userSchema:-

```
let userSchema =  new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
        required: true
    }
    phoneNo: {
        type: String
        required: true
    }
    questionAnswer: {
        type: [questionAnswerSchema]
    }
});
```

and here is my questionAnswerSchema

```
let questionAnswerSchema = new Schema({
    question: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Question',
        required: true
    },
    answer: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
});
```

my question schema:-

```
let questionFields = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    questionType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    sampleAnswer: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});
```

and my query:-

```
let recommendationList = await userModel.aggregate([
    {
       $unwind: {
           path: '$questionAnswer',
           preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
       }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'questions',
            localField: 'questionAnswer.question',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'questionAnswer'
        }
    },
])
```

and i want a expected output like this

```
{
    name: 'foo',
    phoneNo: '1234567890'
    questionAnswer: [
        {
            question: {
                title: 'This is the first question'
                questionType: 'longQuestion'
                sampleAnswer: 'this is dummy sample answer'
            }
            answer: 'this is my first actual answer'
        },
        {
            question: {
                title: 'This is the second question'
                questionType: 'shortQuestion'
                sampleAnswer: 'this is dummy sample answer'
            }
            answer: 'this is my second actual answer'
        },

    ]
}
```

Comment: How does the `questions` Schema look like? @Asif

Comment: @PrasantaBose i have updated my question with question schema. please have a look

Comment: see my answer below. @Asif

Comment: I wasn't sure how you inserted the data So, provided an insertion code to. Might be unnecessary if data is inserted right. @Asif

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some more filters in your aggregation pipeline. Following is the complete aggregate query on your model. Hope it helps!

```
let recommendationList = await userModel.aggregate([
    {
      $unwind: unwindQuestion
    },
    {
      $lookup: questionLookup
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$datingQuestionAnswer.question'
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        datingQuestionAnswer: {
          $mergeObjects: ['$datingQuestionAnswer', '$datingQuestionAnswer']
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        datingQuestionAnswer: { $push: '$datingQuestionAnswer' },
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        datingQuestionAnswer: 1,
        pageNo: 1
      }
    },
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's some issue with `_id` being used with `$lookup`. So, you can use the following example. It uses the populate functionality from mongoose.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const util = require('util')
// util is only used to see a well structured result in console. Else unnecesary
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/stackoverflow', {useNewUrlParser: true});

const questionAnswerSchema = new Schema({
    question: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'question',
        required: true
    },
    answer: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
});

const userSchema =  new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phoneNo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    questionAnswer: {
        type: [questionAnswerSchema]
    }
});


const questionFields = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    questionType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    sampleAnswer: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const userModel = mongoose.model("user", userSchema)
const questionModel = mongoose.model("question", questionFields)

// Uncomment Insert section and Comment the find section to insert test docs.
// And, keep it current state to fetch results only

// Insert section :
// new questionModel({
//     title: "question title 1",
//     questionType: "type 1",
//     sampleAnswer: "answer 1"
// }).save().then(result => {
//     return new userModel({
//         name: "joker",
//         phoneNo: "999999999",
//         questionAnswer: [
//             {
//                 question: result._id,
//                 answer: "internal answer"
//             }
//         ]
//     }).save()

// }).then((result)=>{
//     console.log("save result", result)
// }).catch(err => {
//     console.log("err",err)
// })

// Find Section
userModel
    .findOne({ name: "joker" })
    .populate("questionAnswer.question","-_id") // may not pass "-_id" as an argument it's here just to hide _id from result
    .then(result => {
        console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null, true /* enable colors */))
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("err", err)
    })
```

Comment: actully user field  that i have shown is simpler , however i have lots of fields in my user schema, and location field also, thats why i am using aggregrate along with the geoNear , so i have to implement this by using aggregate.

Comment: Can you share your model structure or what you are trying to implement? Like you can populate any field you want with this.